# A non-collectible assembly may not reference a collectible assembly

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq

I was trying to migrate .Net Core console app and tests from 2.1 to 3.1 and got a problem in my tests. I was using `Moq` library and it was working fine. After migration i started to get `A non-collectible assembly may not reference a collectible assembly` when trying to access any mocked objects. I have reproduced same behavior in completely new project. I was not able to find any relevant information on this topic. I have tested it with both `MSTest` and `Xunit`. Is this a `Moq` library issue or .Net Core 3.1 should use different approach to such cases?

```
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace NetCore3.Tests
{
    public interface IMyInterface{ }
    
    public class UnitTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
            var tmp = mock.Object; // this line throwing exception
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
NetCore3.Tests.UnitTest.Test

System.NotSupportedException: A non-collectible assembly may not reference a collectible assembly.

System.NotSupportedException
A non-collectible assembly may not reference a collectible assembly.
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.GetTypeRef(QCallModule module, String strFullName, QCallModule refedModule, String strRefedModuleFileName, Int32 tkResolution)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.GetTypeRefNested(Type type, Module refedModule, String strRefedModuleFileName)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.GetTypeTokenWorkerNoLock(Type type, Boolean getGenericDefinition)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.GetTypeTokenInternal(Type type, Boolean getGenericDefinition)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(Type interfaceType)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.ClassEmitter..ctor(ModuleScope modulescope, String name, Type baseType, IEnumerable`1 interfaces, TypeAttributes flags, Boolean forceUnsigned)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.BuildClassEmitter(String typeName, Type parentType, IEnumerable`1 interfaces)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator.Init(String typeName, ClassEmitter& emitter, Type proxyTargetType, FieldReference& interceptorsField, IEnumerable`1 interfaces)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithoutTargetGenerator.GenerateType(String typeName, Type proxyTargetType, Type[] interfaces, INamingScope namingScope)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<GenerateCode>b__0(String n, INamingScope s)
   at Castle.Core.Internal.SynchronizedDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.ObtainProxyType(CacheKey cacheKey, Func`3 factory)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance()
   at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject()
   at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
   at NetCore3.Tests.UnitTest.Test() in C:\Work\NetCore3\NetCore3.Tests\UnitTest1.cs:line 14
```

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.6.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.14.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.2"/>
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.3.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/collectible-assemblies.  If you search for that error message, there are issues with Castle proxies and collectible assemblies.  Otherwise, I'm intrigued to see what happens from this question

Comment: Long shot here, what IDE are you using?

Comment: JetBrains Rider at the moment.

Comment: Did it just update to the very latest EAP (2020.2 EAP 8), and brake in the exact same way mine did :)

Comment: Yes, got your point. Just tested in VS Code and it is working fine.

Comment: You should report the issue to JetBrains!

Comment: Yes, just checked in Rider 2020.1.4, working fine as well. Sorry was my fault, forgot that was using EAP product. Will report to JetBrains.

Comment: Done: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-48151

Comment: Seems like they already had similar bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-48135

Comment: I have the same problem with Rider EAP8

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the sake of anyone else landing on this from google...

We are using the latest Rider/ReSharper EAP (2020.2 EAP 8) which has introduced this bug when:

- Running tests via the Rider/ReSharper test runner
- The test project references and uses a mocking library that attempts to generate dynamic proxies (Moq, NSubstitute, etc...)

This has been fixed by JetBrains in their development branch and will be fixed in the next EAP. You can track this here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-48134

**Update**: EAP 9 is out which fixes this  You can use JetBrains Toolbox to update.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Experiencing the exact same problem!

Comment: I see this same behavior using Visual Studio 2019 and MSTest with NSubstitute and ReSharper EAP 8.  This is not just Rider?

Comment: @SkipSaillors If you are using the Resharper test runner, that's basically the same code as Rider, so try using the Visual Studio Test Runner, it should not have the problem.

Comment: I am using the VS test runner, as a workaround, thanks.  It works.  I am anxious for R# to resolve this.  The main reason I got hooked on R# in the first place was because I liked the test runner.

Comment: 2020.2 EAP 9 was released today

Comment: EAP 9 fixes my R# test-runner issues